# the rigth way to execute a php script from crontab

Tags: php, cron

I have a .php script that includes other php scripts and as final result a db is updated and a report file has been created.

if I manually call it from a browser all works fine.

I tried to call it from the crontab with the following syntax

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/PATH/myscript.php
```

and at the planned time, it seems to stop at the first include(); and die.
I added a mail(); sending after each include();

If I call the file from the browser I receive all the 5 mails, when it's called from the crontab, I receive only the first email

Where am I doing wrong?

*edit:
I tried to call always the first script and I received all the mail. It seems the second script contains something that is stopping the code but ONLY is it's called by the cron

Comment: Did you look for errors in the logs. They normally point you in the right direction

Comment: You say it works fine from a browser, but have you tried it from the command line yourself?

Comment: unfortunately I dont's have access to the server or to the command shell but I only can manage the cron from the cpanel

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```
php -q /home/PATH/myscript.php
```

As [per this answer by St. Woland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2063327), the `-q` flag:

> The -q flag suppresses HTTP header output.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a php script like this:

```
php -f script.php
```

If you want to use another *php.ini* (what often happens with console apps), use

```
php -c path/where/php.ini -f script.php
```

type

```
php --help
```

for more options.